# Is scrapy supported on google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, scrapy

It has following dependencies:
- Twisted 2.5.0, 8.0 or above
- lxml or libxml2 (if using libxml2, version 2.6.28 or above is highly recommended)
- simplejson
- pyopenssl

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use C extensions on App Engine, which rules out lxml and (I believe) libxml2 and pyopenssl.

I doubt most of what Twisted does is possible in the App Engine sandbox either; you can't directly open sockets or spawn threads.

EDIT (January 2013): The Python 2.7 runtime does include some C extensions, including lxml. However, it's still not possible to use C extensions that aren't provided by Google with the runtime; most likely scrapy is still unusable at this time.

Comment: As an alternative, you can try the [URL Fetch API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/) and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: In GAE you can import prepared lxml and pycrypto libraries: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

Answer (score 3):

No but you could try AWS (http://dev.scrapy.org/wiki/AmazonEC2)

Answer (score 3):

Update for 2019:
Scrapy indeed works on GAE. I can confirm that Scrapy can be deployed on GAE Python 3 standard environment using [ScrapyRT](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyrt).

Your `scrapy.cfg` file must be in the same directory as `app.yaml` to be picked up accordingly and a minimal setup would look like this:

```
runtime: python37

instance_class: F2

env_variables:
  PORT: 8080

entrypoint: scrapyrt -i 0.0.0.0 -p $PORT -s LOG_DIR=/tmp
```

Note how `LOG_DIR` is set to `/tmp` which is most likely not what anyone would want for production environment. I might extend this answer once i figured out how to approach this appropriately.

Comment: I have been trying to deploy my scraper using your app.yaml config and eventho it deploy with success, I am unable to fetch results like in local using my app url:

https://<my_app>.ew.r.appspot.com:8080/crawl.json?spider_name=<my_spider>&url=<my_url>

Comment: To my own question: 
It worked with ```entrypoint: scrapyrt -p $PORT -s LOG_DIR=/tmp```and no port in the url

Comment: Yes @Maxatton,  I believe GAE Standard Env requires your app to host on port 8080 internally but serves externally to port 80 and 433 (HTTPS); So no port specifier in the URL.